# Getting junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in [package] when using Unit and Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I added the following dependencies to my android project:

```
 // Unit testing dependencies
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
// Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

And create a test using junit4 api (an example, Adder is a simple class that sums ints):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class AdderTest {

    @Test
    public void testValidAdd() {
        Adder adder = new Adder();
        assertEquals(adder.add(1,1), 2);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I get:

> Running tests
>   Test running started
>   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.test.myapp.AdderTest
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>   at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
>   Finish

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472319/junit-framework-assertionfailederror-no-tests-found-in-xyz-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983085/876603), but nothing helps.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong / have any input?

Comment: Unit tests belong in the `test` folder, so use `testCompile`. Also, you do not need the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: This was just an example. I do need in my original project to use mocks. In addition, the code that I'm testing uses android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, and it returns null when I run it as a unit test. If I run it as an Android instrumentation test, won't it return the actual matcher?

Comment: Post your code for clarity. You should be using Robolectric for unit testing. It will instrument the classes you need so you do not need mocks *for everything*.

Comment: I do need to use Mockito to mock some responses of class dependencies.
Using @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) in the test class + adding MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); to my setup() method does make my test work as a unit test (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS does not return null).

Is this the way to go though? It seems complex :/

Comment: It is not complex at all. Please see my Android Gradle Templaet here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/AndroidGradleTemplate/blob/master/Example-AllLibraries/build.gradle

Answer (score 16):

These aren't unit tests, they are instrumentation test. I had the same problem and solved it by adding these lines to module's build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
    }
}
```

You have to add the runner in dependencies, i suggest you espresso:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

**EDIT:**

I have forgotten about the annotation. Just remove @RunWith and make a @Before method with line:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

or:

```
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

I have to mention this way is not recommended. To use the second one, you have to add dependencies with dex-maker for mockito:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2') {
        exclude module: 'mockito-core'
    }
```

Since you have added mockito, we have to exclude mockito core from the new dependency. It already contains the normal dex-maker module.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The line you're looking for is in [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L29). This seems to support the statement that the `testInstrumentationRunner` directive is required.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an Android Instrumentation test. By default, the Android test runner doesn't run on JUnit4, it runs on JUnit3 using subclasses of [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html).

You'll need to revert to manual calls to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`, with an optional tear-down call to `Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`. Of course, calls directly to `Mockito.mock` (and such) will still work.

As an alternative, there is an [official JUnit4 runner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html), which can be installed from the [Android Support Test Library](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide). By invoking this Instrumentation rather than the default test runner, you can run JUnit4 tests on your device, including using `MockitoJUnitRunner` or `MockitoRule`.

Comment: Actually, the default runner for modern Android gradle projects is Junit 4 now.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sure, but only if you set the instrumentation test runner as Szymon's answer. The built-in runner is JUnit3.8, so an override is still required; once it is overridden you're using the Android Support Test Library as in my answer.